# How to expand a Canvas when I place an object on it?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating multiple objects on a `Tkinter.Canvas`. Here the problem is that some of the objects are going out of the canvas. How can I expand the canvas to show all objects even with a Scrollbar?
Here is the sample code I am using:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
f=Frame(root)
f.grid()
w=Canvas(f)
line1=w.create_line(50,50,150,150, width=5)
line2=w.create_line(100,100,100,350, width=3)
line3=w.create_line(150,150,150,450, width=3)
w.grid(row=0, column=0)
u=Frame(f)
u.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Here `line2` and `line3` are out of the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create two `Scrollbar`s and set them as the `xscrollcommand` and `yscrollcommand` options of the canvas. Then, when you configure the `scrollregion` with the maximum width and height, the scollbars will growth if needed.

If you replace the `Canvas` of your code with this extremely basic implementation you'll see the result:

```
from Tkinter import *

class ScrollableCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **options):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        Canvas.__init__(self, self.frame, *args, **options)
        self.xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, command=self.xview, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, command=self.yview)
        self.config(xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
    def create_line(self, *args, **options):
        Canvas.create_line(self, args, **options)
        self._resize(*args)
    def _resize(self, *args):
        maxwidth = max(args[0], args[2], int(self['width']))
        maxheight = max(args[1], args[3], int(self['height']))
        self.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, maxwidth, maxheight))
    def grid(self, *args, **options):
        self.frame.grid(*args, **options)
        Canvas.grid(self, row=0, column=0)
        self.xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
        self.yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the size you want when you create the `Canvas` object:

```
w=Canvas(f, width=200, height=500)
```

Alternatively, you can reconfigure many widgets after they're created via their `config()` method:

```
w.config(width=200, height=500)
```

Here what some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/) I found says:

> Before we look at the widgets, let's take a look at how some of their
>   common attributes—such as sizes, colors and fonts—are specified.
>
> • Each widget has a set of options that affect its appearance and
>   behavior—attributes such as fonts, colors, sizes, text labels, and
>   such.
>
> • You can specify options when calling the widget's constructor using
>   keyword arguments such as`text='PANIC!'`or`height=20`.
>
> • After you have created a widget, you can later change any option by
>   using    the widget's`.config()`method. You can retrieve the current
>   setting    of any option by using the widget's`.cget()`method.

Comment: if i fix my frame size will canvas scroll?

Comment: If you create and connect some [`scrollbar`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/scrollbar.html) widgets to the canvas it will.